# generate unique array base on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have few checkbox, what I want is to build a unique array list base on the checkbox value, if the checkbox is checked, push it to the list, if the checked checkbox is already in the list, remove it from the list.

http://jsbin.com/bojinudelo/edit?js,console,output

What's the problem of my code below?

```
generateFilter = (e) => {

    let temp = [];
    temp = this.state.arr;

    if(temp.indexOf(this.state.arr) > -1){
      delete temp[e.target.name]
    }else{
      temp.push(e.target.name);
    }

    this.setState({arr:temp})
    console.log(this.state.arr)
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
         <input onChange={this.generateFilter} type="checkbox" name="apple"/>
         <input onChange={this.generateFilter} type="checkbox" name="samsung"/>
      </div>    
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is, you are checking the index of wrong item, Instead of checking the index of `this.state.arr`, check the index of `e.target.value`, as well as deleting in a wrong way.

temp is an `array` not an `Object`, so instead of using `delete`, you need to use the `splice` and pass the index of item.

Use this function:

```
generateFilter = (e) => {

      let temp = this.state.arr.slice(), 
          index = temp.indexOf(e.target.name);

      if(index != -1){
        temp.splice(index, 1);
      }else{
        temp.push(e.target.name);
      }

      this.setState({arr:temp})
      console.log(temp)
  }
```

Check the working code: http://jsbin.com/tatakamobu/1/edit?js,console,output

Run this snippet:

```js
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      arr: []
    }
  }      

  generateFilter = (e) => {

      let temp = this.state.arr.slice(), 
          index = temp.indexOf(e.target.name);

      if(index != -1){
        temp.splice(index, 1);
      }else{
        temp.push(e.target.name);
      }

      this.setState({arr:temp})
      console.log(temp)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
         <input onChange={this.generateFilter} type="checkbox" name="apple"/>
         <input onChange={this.generateFilter} type="checkbox" name="samsung"/>
      </div>    
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='react_example'/>
```